# Arrays_como setar mais valores em um Array?

Tags: javascript, array

Estou iniciando agora em Js e tenho uma coisa que não sei como faço, Sempre que a Função "armazenador" for executada, eu preciso que ela pegue valores de um input, crie novas posições em um array, e armazene os valores nesta novas posições, seria mais o menos o seguinte :

```
let agregado;
let armazena;
let i;

function armazenador() {
    agregado = document.querySelectorAll('.entNots input');
    let a = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < (i + 5); i++) {
        armazena[i] = agregado[a];
        a++;
    }
}
```

sempre que fosse executado armazenador, ele preencheria mais 5 posições sem sobrepor as anteriores, e preciso que não tenha limitações de quantidade de posições livres.

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa matéria do Medium, vai esclarecer a sua duvida e aprender mais. [https://medium.com/@oieduardorabelo/javascript-set-vs-array-quando-e-como-usar-cf05a7a6ce54](https://medium.com/@oieduardorabelo/javascript-set-vs-array-quando-e-como-usar-cf05a7a6ce54)

Comment: Dê um exemplo da saída desejada e dos valores do input.

Comment: Não é a solução mas esse loop  for tá sem sentido, logo na primeira iteração i já é menor que i+5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var x = 0;
let armazena=[];
let agregado = document.querySelectorAll("input.entNots");

function armazenador()
{
for (const val of agregado) {
    armazena.push(val.value);
}

 x++;

 elementosAdicionados();
}

function elementosAdicionados()
{
   var e = [];   
    
   for (var y=0; y<armazena.length; y++)
   {
     e.push(armazena[y]);
   }
   console.log(e);
}
```

```html
<input class="entNots" value="">
<input class="entNots" value="">
<input class="entNots" value="">
<input class="entNots" value="">
<input class="entNots" value="">

<input type="button" id="button1" value="Add" onclick="armazenador();"></input>
```

[**document.querySelectorAll**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) -  retorna todos os elementos no documento que correspondem aos seletores CSS especificados, no caso class `entNots`

[**push ()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) - adiciona novos itens ao final de um array e retorna o novo comprimento desse array.

[**for-of**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) - Este loop é específico para iterar entre os elementos de uma lista. Ele percorre objetos iterativos, chamando uma função personalizada com instruções a serem executadas para o valor de cada objeto distinto.

**Sintaxe:**

```
for (variavel of iteravel){
    declaração;
}
```

**Onde:**

`variável`: a cada iteração, um valor de uma propriedade diferente é atribuído à variável;

`iteravel`: objeto cujos atributos serão iterados.

Exemplo:

```js
 let menu = ['segunda - Feijão tropeiro', 'terça - macarronada', 'quarta - Baião de dois', 'quinta - Feijoada', 'sexta - CHOPADA'];
    
for (let value of menu) {
  console.log(value);
}
```